# How to prevent a form from closing in btnClose_Click

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to prevent the user from closing the form when the `DialogResult.No` is `True` in vb.net. I also tried `e.cancel=true` but it does not work in `btnClose_click`. I mentioned that is not `FormClosingEventArgs`. I want put it in `btnClose_Click`.

Code copied from OP comment;

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    If CustomMessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", Buttons.YesNo, Icons.Question,
                          AnimateStyle.ZoomIn) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            ' ---Close The Form
        End If
    ElseIf Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Or Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None Then
        ' ---Not Closing the Form
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean you have a button `btnClose` on your form and when user clicks it, you don't want your form to close?

Comment: No I mean I have a event ''Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click'' , i want to not closing my form when dialogResult is No.

Comment: Don't let the button set DialogResult: set the button's `DialogResult` property to none. Anyway, if you have a closebutton but you don't want to close the form, why do you have a closebutton in the first place? Lastly, if you have advanced logic in your closebutton handler that should decide if the form should be closed or not, you should put that logic in the `FormClosing` event and set the `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel` property accordingly; that's the reason why that event exists in the first place.

Comment: Or, in your button's event handler, you should *not* set the form's `DialogResult` property if you do *not* want to close the form (yet). (And make sure that the button's `DialogResult` property is set to None too.)

Comment: Show us the code!  ALWAYS show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FormClosing Event (or Closing befoce NET 2.0). This Event occurs before the close event and can be canceled.

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs ) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If CustomMessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", Buttons.YesNo, Icons.Question,
                          AnimateStyle.ZoomIn) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
       e.Cancel = true ' <<<< close event will not occur, form stays open
    End If
End Sub
```

[FormClosing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: EventArgs doesn't have a .Cancel property... did you mean to illustrate the FormClosing event with the code??

Comment: The Cancel property only exists in the FormClosing event